# Trying to read SQL Server Database for the first time but SqlDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable) is breaking it

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database-connection

This is my first time using a database.

This is my database, it uses just Windows Authentication.

[image]

And I'm using the following code to try to connect to it and gather data:

```
        string connectionString =   "user id=USERNAME;" +
                                    "server=SERVERNAME;" +
                                    "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                    "database=claytonDatabase; " +
                                    "connection timeout=30";

        try
        {
            SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            thisConnection.Open();

            string Get_Data = "SELECT * FROM dbo.location";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Get_Data);

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("locationTable");

            sda.Fill(dt); // this line kills it

            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("db error" + ex.ToString());
        }
```

The `sda.Fill(dt);` line is what breaks the program, resulting in this error if I don't use the `try` statement:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: 'The invocation of the constructor on type
>   'clayton.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints
>   threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

And this if I do use the try:

```
at line 0</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'clayton.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'. ---&amp;gt; System.InvalidOperationException: Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.GetConnection3(DbDataAdapter adapter, IDbCommand command, String method)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at clayton.MainWindow.ConnectToDatabase() in c:\Users\cclayto\Desktop\C#\clayton\clayton\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 87
   at clayton.MainWindow..ctor() in c:\Users\cclayto\Desktop\C#\clayton\clayton\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 34
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I'm not sure how to even test if the problem is with the `Fill` command or if I'm not actually connecting successfully at all to the SQL database. Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: refactor your code to utilize the using(){}` construct..

Comment: @MethodMan, I was using that before and I got a similar error. I've tried code that I copied from a few different tutorials with no success, which makes me think the problem is with how I'm connecting.

Comment: Line 3 and line Position 9 is not the location of the Fill call. What about your XAML file?

Comment: @Steve If I comment that line out it won't break on startup though. In my XAML file line three is `        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"` and line 9 is blank. I don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never set the connection string on the CMD object you create

```
cmd.Connection = thisConnection
```

The error message, although somewhat cryptic, does tell you what the error was...

at line 0System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 
'The invocation of the constructor on type 'clayton.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'. ---&gt; System.InvalidOperationException: Fill: **SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.**

Comment: Wondering where was the inner exception. Nice catch

Comment: Thanks a bunch. You were fastest and right on the money.

Answer (score 2):

`Line 3, Position 9` is not the location of the Fill method, but your code will fail if called by some binding from the XAML file because you have an SqlCommand not associated with a valid SqlConnection, thus when you call Fill there is no way to find the database.

```
    string connectionString =   "user id=USERNAME;" +
                                "server=SERVERNAME;" +
                                "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                "database=claytonDatabase; " +
                                "connection timeout=30";

    string Get_Data = "SELECT * FROM dbo.location";
    try
    {
        using(SqlConnection thisConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Get_Data, thisConnection))
        using(SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            thisConnection.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("locationTable");
            sda.Fill(dt); 
            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
            {
                 foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
                 {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                 }
            }
       }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
        MessageBox.Show("db error " + ex.Message);
   }
```

Not sure about the error that you mention in your comments below. You could try to change your loop in this way to check if some of the fields are null

```
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(dataRow.IsNull("Equipment Number") ? "NULL" : 
                           dataRow.Field<string>("Equipment Number"));
         Console.WriteLine(dataRow.IsNull("Equipment Description") ? "NULL" :
                           dataRow.Field<string>("Equipment Description"));
    }
```

As a side note, avoid the use of column names with spaces. They will give you more troubles than advantages.

Comment: You should probably dispose the SqlDataAdapter and DataTable as well.

Comment: Should this process take long? Because now I'm not getting an error message but it seems like it's stuck in an infinite loop. I did a `MessageBox.Show` instead of `Console.WriteLine` in the foreach loop and it only did the first row and then stopped and hasn't left the function.

Comment: How many record do you have in that table? Also if some of that fields are null, trying to print them out will give a null reference exception

Comment: There are only two columns with a few thousands rows. If I comment out the inner `foreach`, it will iterate through the rows, but the inner `foreach` seems to get stuck. Is something wrong with `dataRow.ItemArray` that you can tell?

Comment: `dataRow.ItemArray` in order to see the 2 fields for example it's an array so you would need to do the following just to see  both for example `Console.WriteLine(item[0] + " " +  item[1]);`